# Possible to exclude a folder from Dropbox (even though it's in Dropbox folder)?

Tags: dropbox, mamp

I currently have my MAMP htdocs folder within my Dropbox folder (so I can sync files for different workstations). I also have a client that isn't comfortable with having their files on Dropbox.

Anyone know if it's possible to exclude this one folder from Dropbox completely, even know it lives right there in the Dropbox folder? (Of course, moving the folder outside of Dropbox is easy enough, but then it's outside of my MAMP environment.)

Is it possible to set up an alias or something? Is there something really simple I'm missing here? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using the Selective Sync feature of Dropbox

https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is really the only way to do it. +1

Comment: But doesn't this leave the folder on Dropbox? I basically want to remove the folder from Dropbox completely -- and leave it on my computer (in the Dropbox folder). Maybe this is more of a MAMP issue.

Comment: you could pause syncing while you create the directory and deselect it from the selective sync box. Or, you could deselect it from the selective sync and then delete it via the website interface on dropbox.com (https://www.dropbox.com/help/40/en)

Comment: Thanks Joakim! That second approach worked like a charm. Here's what I did: Moved folder outside of Dropbox on my computer, deleted folder from Dropbox web interface. Checked folder in selective sync. Created folder again in Dropbox on my computer. Moved files back in. Awesome.

Comment: That still looks too complicated to me just to do this simple thing. There should be a better way! :/